# Deciding winner with flush on table (Texas Hold em no limit)

Tags: poker-texas-holdem, poker

I am creating my own poker game prototype as a hobby project.
The game calculates the combinations every player has and decides a 5 card hand
to be used when calculating a winner if players have the same combination.

The attached images show my exact scenario.

In this specific case there is a flush on the table and HUMANPLAYER and Ramon Tandheelkunde (a Dutch randomized name for fun) both split the pot because they have exactly the same five card hand. (See the image with the log). Lisa Rutte however, loses because her 9 of Hearts is added to her five card hand. Is this supposed to happen or should Lisa also win or be the only one to win since she has a hearts in her hand unlike the others?

Edit: Lisa Rutte actually gets a six cards hand instead of a five cards hand. This obviously is a bug but my issue is with her 9 of Hearts getting added at all making her lose. This happens because the game compares each five cards hand from left to right making Lisa kicked out of the race because her 9 is lower than the J's on that spot in the five card hands of the other players.

Thanks for thinking with me! :)

Kind regards,

Ricardo

[image: The game board]

[image: The log showing the five card hands]

Comment: It does, but is is not a fun answer haha. So basically I have to code the whole algorithm that gets explained in the answer of that post just for the three rare scenarios described in that post he is answering to. xD

Comment: And the thing that confuses me. All players MUST make the best five cards hand available. So it seems logical that the 9 gets added to the five cards hand of Lisa between the 6 and the J. But it's not fair she loses because of that.

Comment: She should win because the 9 gets included.  All have A,K,J.  Lisa has a 9 vs Ramon and HUMANPLAYER 6.

Comment: The real problem is why your interpreter gives Lisa a 6 card hand instead of 5.

Comment: Thanks, is it okay then to say: the player with the highest card of the same suit as the table flush wins, if no one has a same suit card in hand then the pot is split? Because you are only allowed to look at five cards. 

Let's talk straights for a moment. If there is a straight on the table and no one has an adjacent card then everyone has the same five card hand so the pot is split.

Is it OK to apply this logic to a digital poker game without any intention to let players play with real money?

Comment: Even if someone has an adjacent card, there could still be a tie. If there's a 3,4,5,6,7 on the table and a player has a 2 in their hand, their best hand excludes the 2. A good way to think of this is, everyone has 7 cards available (2 in their hand, 5 on the board) and must make the best 5 card hand they can. Take everyones top hand and compare them to each other.